# glActiveTexture or glActiveTextureARB?

Tags: opengl

When I should load one or another in my own loader code? On Xorg + Mesa-based systems there is no guarantee of zero pointer returned if feature is not supported in current context, which results in catastrophic function calls, Khronos recommends to look up extension name with result of glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS).

Different sources associate both of those with "ARB_multitexture"

Comment: Do you want to use it as an extension, or are you relying on your implementation to support at least GL version 1.2?

Comment: @NicolBolas no implementation I encountered or work with got the prototype of either in headers. I attempted to use Qt's QOpenGLFunctions, but it leads to a disasters because that one doesn't even check if pointer is non-zero and it doesn't check extensions, so non-zero pointers for glActiveTexture (glActiveTextureARB not supported) in some cases are invalid. I load  pointers and have an own equivalent of QOpenGLFunctionsPrivate. Some of implementations support 1.1 only, I plan contengencies for that.

Comment: "*no implementation I encountered or work with got the prototype of either in headers.*" Implementations don't provide prototypes; your OpenGL loader does.

Comment: @NicolBolas the only loader is my own code, no compatible implementation across targets exist (none at all, a libext , which _got_ prototypes for static OpenGL versions, old GLEE, incorrectly built GLEW with wrong call conventions, and a working GLEW on Windows).bThat's why I have question

Comment: You keep using the word "implementation" as if it is a synonym for "OpenGL loader"; they're not the same thing. And yes, there are loaders that work "across targets". GLee is outdated and hasn't been supported in years, but GLEW works just fine, as does GLAD.

Comment: @NicolBolas Not if platforms are exotic closed-sourced  or linux-from scratch closed OSes I have no authority to modify. The only library they all have is loader in Qt 4 -5 and it does work only on Windows too, but only in debug mode (known issue, neglected)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228261/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-swift-friday-pie).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way OpenGL code typically works with a loader is that it has some baseline version of OpenGL functionality. If the implementation cannot provide even that version of GL, then the program simply cannot execute and shuts down. If it has some optional features that it can work with, then it uses extensions to test if those are available.

So you would load core OpenGL functions up to and including that version, but you would then rely on extensions for everything else.

Since `glActiveTexture` comes from OpenGL 1.2, if your minimum GL version is 2.1, then you would use `glActiveTexture` and not care about the extension version of the function. If the minimum version is 1.1, you could use `glActiveTextureARB` and ignore the core version even if the implementation supports it.

The problem you may eventually face is that some core functionality doesn't have an exact extension equivalent, or an extension equivalent at all. For example, the ARB extensions that provide access to GLSL via ARB_shader_objects and the rest. These APIs are *very different* from the core GL 2.0 functions. Not just by the ARB suffix, but even by the type of the shader objects. You can't transparently write code that works with both.

Comment: Got it , so I have somehow determine version of OpenGL. and I anticipated that last problem too, thankfully it's not a pressing issue currently and there is a level of abstraction between render code and the rest.

Comment: I also right now found why Qt failed and that it actually failed on it. Their code plainly expects that driver version string starts either with "OpenGL ES" or with "1.", "2.", etc. It does only on Windows. On MESA systems it stably starts... with a quotation mark and then whatever they expected(for some reason Mesa adds quotes). On MacOS things are even hairier.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie: Then those implementations violate the specification. `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` is *required* to start with a number of the form `X.Y` (for desktop OpenGL). If those "MESA systems" are producing different values, then they're broken.

Comment: yes, I know? But when glxinfo outputs it, it's without quotes, when I take it on, e.g., on Ubuntu, it starts with quote  `"3.0 MESA 10.1.4"`. Qt returns 1.0 and other loaders do not flop, but have issues